# on/on to/onto a plate

Tags: prepositions

> He tried an oyster at the buffet and liked it, so he fished quite a few more **on/on to/onto** a plate and went back to his table.

Which is the correct preposition to use here?

Answer (score 1):

**On** is a preposition of place used to express location of an object at a given point of time.

> The cat is sleeping on the table.

The cat was already sleeping on top of the table when we saw it. Therefore, no movement occurred (for e.g. the cat jumping upon the table and then going to sleep).

**Onto** is a preposition generally used to express “on top of,” “to a position on,” “upon.”

> The cat jumped onto the table.

The above sentence is synonymous with saying "The cat jumped upon the table". This sentence suggests a movement taking place, that is the cat jumping on top of the table.

**On to** in a more general sense is used when "on" is part of the verb phrase.

> I held on to my cat while standing in the queue (for the ticket).

***"held on"*** is a phrasal verb, while ***"to"*** is acting as the preposition which takes "my cat".

---

Now I believe you can identify exactly which preposition fits in your case. **Hint:** Look if there is movement or not. If you have any further doubts, comment on my answer. I will try my best at clearing them.